# WPF auto-scrolling to items in a ListBox

Tags: wpf

When one presses a letter (or a sequence of letters) in a windows combobox or in a list, automatically the first item that starts with the given letter, is selected.

Is there a declarative way to do the same thing for a WPF ListBox that has it's items bound by the `ItemsSource`-property and the `ItemsTemplate` set to a `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put on your listbox:

```
IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
TextSearch.TextPath="Prop"
```

where `Prop` is the path to the property of the bound object you want to use for text searching.