# Keypress to navigate to list item starting with that alphabet in listview wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

When the focus is on the listview and I press any alphabet the listview should scroll down to the first list item starting with that alphabet key. ListView contains more than 2 columns (Name and Price).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF auto-scrolling to items in a ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712566/wpf-auto-scrolling-to-items-in-a-listbox)

Comment: @daniel_sweetser Thank you.